# How do I resolve IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I try to let user add comments to blog post am making...
When I run makemigrations and migrate, everything seemed fine . The form displayed well but shows the following error when I fill the form and click on the submit button.
**Django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.author_id**

Am new to Django and following a tutorial. The tutorial doesn't have users except the super user. I learnt about users and so I let user register to use the blog. The tutorial provided a name field in the form so commenter can enter their name. Here, I want to use the current user for this field(see my models.py below to see how I have done this). 
Any help to solve this will be appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    comment = models.TextField()   
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.author} on {self.post}'
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('comment',)
```

**views.py**

```
login_required
def post_detail(request, post, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk, slug=post, status='published')
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,
        'post_detail.html',
        {'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'new_comment': new_comment,
        'comment_form': comment_form})
```

PS: I have seen similar questions like this and deleted my migrations file and re-ran migrations but it didn't still work.

Answer (score 0):

In the if `comment.is_valid():` block,

Before;

```
new_comment.save()
```

Add,

```
new_comment.author = request.user
```